# Little/ a little: "If you love whole fruit, there’s little evidence that indulging in it is bad for your health"

Tags: grammar, difference, quantifiers

I have always thought that the difference between *little* and *a little* is that the former is used to express a negative idea like for example *there's little support for my proposal*, and the latter is used to express a positive idea like *don't worry, there is a little salt in the soup.*

But this changed when I came across the following sentence from [time](http://time.com/5301984/can-you-eat-too-much-fruit):

> If you love whole fruit, there’s little evidence that indulging in it—even a whole lot of it—is bad for your health

Little evidence, here, is good news, right? Because one can indulge in fruit with no potential harm, so why shouldn't it be *a little* evidence? Google shows that *a little* occurs with evidence 277 times, whereas *little evidence* occurs 120,000 times.

Comment: No, *salt* is specific, *evidence* is not.

Answer (score 2):

The function of *little* is the same in all of these sentences:

> There is little evidence that whole fruit is *good* for you.
>   There is little evidence that whole fruit is *bad* for you.
>   There is little support for my proposal.

In short, negative and positive outcomes have nothing to do with the use of *little*.

---

However, there is a difference between *little* and *a little*.

> There is *little* evidence of X.

This means that there is almost no evidence. It's saying there is essentially an *absence* of evidence. Whatever evidence does exist is not enough to support X.

It's not X that's negative, but the assertion of a lack of evidence that's negative.

---

> There is *a little* evidence of X.

This means that there is actually *some* evidence. That there is some evidence means that it's possible to assert a claim of X. There may not be enough evidence to support it conclusively, but there's enough to not rule it out entirely.

It's not X that's positive, but the assertion of the existence of evidence that's positive.

---

Normally, we would use *a little* if we want to stress something positively, and just *little* if we want to stress something negatively. Typically, it's a good X we want to put a positive spin on and a bad X that we want to put a negative spin on:

> Thankfully, there is a little evidence [positive] that hugs [good] are effective.
>   Thankfully, there is little evidence [negative] that spankings [bad] are effective.

But it doesn't need to be that way:

> Alas, there is a little evidence [positive] that eating live worms [bad] is healthy.
>   Alas, there is little evidence [negative] that eating doughnuts [good] is healthy.